# Passing 2 arguments with more than one word on a command in discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, parameter-passing

Im trying to create a bot that dms everyone assigned with a certain role. The command structure is the following:

> .c role message

example:

> .c students How's the class going?

I managed the *message* arg. using the "*" on the parameters (as shown below). However in my discord we have a lot of roles with more than just one word. How can I build a logic to get the code receive some words as a *role* parameter and another words as the *message*?

```
@bot.command(aliases=['c'])
# Envia DM para as pessoas que tiverem o cargo mencionado
async def convocar(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, dm):
    for membro in role.members:
        pm = await membro.create_dm()
        await pm.send(dm)
        print('mensagem enviada para um membro')
```

Comment: You have to mention the words in double quotes or maybe `commands.Greedy`

Comment: `commands.Greedy` doesn't work, You have to mention the role or use it in double quotes like this. `!c "students 11" Hello class 11 students`

Comment: Hey, it worked haha. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, you can add it as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the role or use it in double quotes like this:

`.c "students" Hello class!`

Thanks Ceres for the answer!